# Python mysql cannot encode tuple

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to Python and mysql database so would like some advise.

First, I tried to import my csv file into mysql database (header were already created).

```
from mysql.connector import errorcode

df = pd.read_csv("Temperature.csv")

user,pw, host,db = 'user', '123','localhost','xyz'


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db,use_pure=True)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
for index, col in df.iterrows():

    data = {
       'year': col[0],
       'mean': col[1],
       'minimum': col[2],
       'maximum': col[3]

     }

### Make sure the code below is indented inside the for loop
    query = insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO Temperature(year,mean, minimum, maximum)"
                            "VALUES (%(year)f, %(mean)f, %(minimum)f, %(maximum)f")

    cursor.execute(query, data) 
    print("Adding row " + str(index))
    cnx.commit() # Make sure data is committed to the database
```

But now I had the problem of, I tried to look online but can't seem to resolve this problem.

```
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

May I know which part went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a json style for data, but it has to be a tuple as it says
like

```
data = (
   col[0],
   col[1],
   col[2],
   col[3]
)
```

Comment: it still doesn't work when I used the code using '()'

Comment: then show us where you define your array col and show what col[0] actually is.and also print out query variable, only to check. And alto encapsule the ina try catch with print("parameterized query failed {}".format(error)) just to be on the save site

Comment: now that i check your code more intensely, you should defently show an error message for you cursor execution because %(maximum)f is missing a ) athte end and that should give you an error